# ListCreateAPIView object has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework

I have these serializers:

```
# Tickets
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        depth = 2

class TicketWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
```

and this view:

```
class Tickets(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  model = Ticket
  serializer_class = TicketSerializer

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = TicketWriteSerializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      self.pre_save(serializer.object)
      self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
      self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
      headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
      serializer = TicketSerializer(serializer.object)
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and in my urls-file I add it like this:

```
  url(r'^tickets/', Tickets.as_view(model=Tickets), name='tickets')
```

for this model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', null=True, blank=True)
    act = models.ForeignKey('Act')
    row = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    seat = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # Price for a seat can go up to 9999.99
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now whenever I call /tickets/ I get:

```
AttributeError at /tickets/

type object 'Tickets' has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

I'm wondering how it comes to that.
What I want is two Serializers so I can send the data "flat" like with ForeignKeys but retrieve them with all their data of depth = 2.

**edit:**
TraceBack:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://localhost:8000/tickets/
>
> Django Version: 1.7.1 Python Version: 3.4.2 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'server', 
>   'rest_framework',  'rest_framework.authtoken') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in
>   get_response
>     111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in
>   wrapped_view
>     57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in
>   view
>     69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
>     403.             response = self.handle_exception(exc) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
>     400.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get
>     493.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
>     76.         self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()) File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in
>   get_queryset
>     296.             return self.model._default_manager.all()
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /tickets/ Exception Value: type
>   object 'Tickets' has no attribute '_default_manager'

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: Added the traceback I get in the browser, none in the console but a:  "GET /tickets/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90211. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You set `model=Tickets` but `Tickets` is your view, not your model.

```
url(r'^tickets/', Tickets.as_view(model=Tickets), name='tickets')
```

Use this instead

```
url(r'^tickets/', Tickets.as_view(model=Ticket), name='tickets')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now all I'm missing is /tickets/{id}/ to only give me the ticket with id... currently it returns all of them. And I'd like to register this with the router as well, not sure how to do that tho. Again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: how can I do Ticket.objects.select_related in this?